# How to determine image format/encoding when using opencv's imread

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mime-types, imread

I am trying to write a simple Feature-detection program in C++ based on OpenCV to be used in a Unix pipe-style chain of tools, meaning the image read in is received via `stdin` and the processed image is output to `stdout`.

Currently I am using OpenCV's `imread`-function to read the image from the `stdin`-stream which by itself works fine, however I need to somehow know the image format being read in so the program's output-image can be encoded accordingly.

I am aware that once the image is read into a OpenCV Mat, it is decoded automatically - so I need to find a way to determine the image format of the original image beforehand.

So far however, I could only come up with kind of a workaround that is reading the image into a buffer first, then using the magic file from the `file` command to probe for a file-type and hereafter passing the buffered data on to OpenCV.

Admittingly not having done any tests about performance I am quite sure this is a very slow way to achieve this as I assume, OpenCV is doing something similar internally upon image decoding, hence detecting the format twice must for sure be slower than having the format detection only be done once.

Is there any more sophisticated way to achieve this goal or can the original image encoding (preferrably!) be accessed natively through OpenCV in any way I might have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're "quite sure" without measuring it that _comparing a few bytes_ will be your performance bottleneck, rather than the I/O operations you're doing to read image data? By all means try to avoid this clunky workaround with `file`'s magic database, but don't do it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: "using OpenCV's imread-function to read the image from the stdin-stream" -- Could you elaborate on that? AFAIK `imread` only reads files based on the file name string given as first argument. | Measure, don't assume. | OpenCV already [implements this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L203) in order to choose the right decoder. It's not exposed, but it's rather [trivial in most cases](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp#L79).